# Как сделать текст по окружности с изображением в центре этой окружности?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, svg-animation

Подскажите пожалуйста, как закрутить текст "БЦ 3,5 Ж ЭЦ 65.0 25.11.2021 30.11.2021" по окружности (d = 35мм) с размещением небольшого изображения (20 х 20мм) в центре этой окружности? Без JS. ну или с JS/

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Погугли circletype js там всё просто...

Comment: @Rudi fа без JS можно как нибудь реализовать?

Comment: без JS можно, если не лень самому вычислять позиции и угол поворота для каждой буквы или возиться с SVG.

Comment: @Dmitry можно без JS реализовать, посмотрите ответ ниже

Comment: @Alexandr_TT большое спасибо!

Comment: @Dmitry Благодарю. Рад был помочь вам. Как новичка информирую: У вас теперь есть возможность, если ответ был полезен, принять его (галочка) и поставить голос "за" (верхний, серый треугольник у ответа)

Comment: Для новичков, похоже, надо вместо стрелочек "палец вверх" показывать))) А вместо галочки "отправить бесплатный подарок" или "поблагодарить за ответ" или что-нибудь в этом роде))

Answer (score 4):

Текст по окружности размещается с помощью команды: [textPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/textPath)

```
                    <!-- Текст на верхнем полукруге -->
  <textPath  xlink:href="#top"   startOffset="9%"> БЦ 3,5 Ж ЭЦ 65.0
    </textPath>
```

Смотрите комментарии в коде:

```html
<style>
.container {
width:25vw;
height:auto;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
          viewBox="0 0 400 400" >  
         
                   <!-- Верхний полукруг -->
   <path id="top" d="M50 200 A150 150 0 1 1 350 200" fill="none" stroke="#111111" stroke-width="2" />
                      <!-- Нижний полукруг -->
<path id="bottom" d="M50 200 A150 150 0 1 0 350 200" fill="none" stroke="#111111" stroke-width="2" />  
                       <!-- Внешний круг -->
  <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="198" fill="none" stroke="grey" stroke-width="4" /> 

<text  dy="-12px" dx="0" font-size="36px" font-family="Times New Roman" font-weight="bold" fill="black" letter-spacing="6"  >  
                     <!-- Текст на верхнем полукруге -->
  <textPath  xlink:href="#top"   startOffset="9%"> БЦ 3,5 Ж ЭЦ 65.0
    </textPath> 
 </text> 
  <text  dy="32px" dx="0" font-size="34px" font-family="Comic Sans MS" font-weight="bold" fill="grey" letter-spacing="2"  >
  <textPath  xlink:href="#bottom"   startOffset="3%"> 25.11.2021 30.11.2021
    </textPath> 
 </text> 
   <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pk4l9.png" x="65" y="60" width="70%" height="70%" />
 </svg>  
 </div>
```

Размер всей картинки регулируйте с помощью изменения - `width:25vw;` в стилях для контейнера.

### Update

Вариант с анимацией вращения изображения при наведении

```css
.container {
width:25vw;
height:auto;
}
#img{
transform-origin:center;
transform-box:fill-box;
-webkit-transition:-webkit-transform .8s ease-in-out;
        transition: transform .8s ease-in-out;
}
#img:hover {
-webkit-transform: rotate(720deg);
          transform: rotate(720deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
          viewBox="0 0 400 400" >  
         
                   <!-- Верхний полукруг -->
   <path id="top" d="M50 200 A150 150 0 1 1 350 200" fill="none" stroke="#111111" stroke-width="2" />
                      <!-- Нижний полукруг -->
<path id="bottom" d="M50 200 A150 150 0 1 0 350 200" fill="none" stroke="#111111" stroke-width="2" />  
                       <!-- Внешний круг -->
  <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="198" fill="none" stroke="grey" stroke-width="4" /> 

<text  dy="-12px" dx="0" font-size="36px" font-family="Times New Roman" font-weight="bold" fill="black" letter-spacing="6"  >  
                     <!-- Текст на верхнем полукруге -->
  <textPath  xlink:href="#top"   startOffset="9%"> БЦ 3,5 Ж ЭЦ 65.0
    </textPath> 
 </text> 
  <text  dy="32px" dx="0" font-size="34px" font-family="Comic Sans MS" font-weight="bold" fill="grey" letter-spacing="2"  >
  <textPath  xlink:href="#bottom"   startOffset="3%"> 25.11.2021 30.11.2021
    </textPath> 
 </text> 
   <image id="img" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pk4l9.png" x="65" y="60" width="70%" height="70%" />
 </svg>  
 </div>
```

Comment: @Dmitry Если ответ вам был полезен, не забудьте поставить галочку и голос upvote